# Laravel - Breadcrumbs module : pass array of arguments

Tags: php, laravel

I am using [this module](http://laravel-breadcrumbs.davejamesmiller.com/en/latest/) .

I defined my Breadcrumbs, and now I'm trying to render in my blade template by doing the following :

```
{!! Breadcrumbs::render($breadcrumbs) !!}
```

The value of `$breadcrumbs` being "*controlled*" by my controller.

The problem is that I would like to be able to pass an array of arguments to this `render()` method, and not only simple strings. Indeed, here are some Breadcrumbs I declared :

```
Breadcrumbs::register('home', function($breadcrumbs)
{
    $breadcrumbs->push('Home', route('home'));
});

/* .... etc .... */

Breadcrumbs::register('style', function($breadcrumbs, $style_name, $style_slug)
{
    $breadcrumbs->parent('styles');
    $breadcrumbs->push($style_name, route('style', $style_slug));
});
```

In this situation, I need to be able to pass an array of arguments to the `render()` method, which will be sent by the Controller to the View.

I tried the following :

```
{!! call_user_func_array(Breadcrumbs::render, $breadcrumbs) !!}}
```

But I get the following error :

> Undefined class constant 'render'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This module has a `renderArray()` method. Next time, I'll read the documentation till the end :)